# Different (incorrect) estimation of SNR values at reception

Tags: snr, gnuradio, usrp

I want to estimate the SNR value at the input of my USRP. To do this, I connect two blocks: **MPSK SNR Estimator** and **MSPK SNR Estimator Probe**.
[image]

Next, I look at the values that I got using the MSPK SNR Estimator block.

QT GUI Histogram Sink:
[image]

Constructed histogram using File Sink.
[image]

The values I get using **MPSK SNR Estimator Probe**. Output to the console.

[image]

If two blocks do the same thing, then I should expect the same results, or values close to each other. But this is not happening.

1. Is it correct to evaluate the SNR at the output of the USRP Sink block?
2. Why do MSPK SNR blocks show such different results?
3. Which of these blocks shows the correct result (I assume the MSPK SNR Estimator Probe)?
4. In this case, how can I extract the evaluation data from the MSPK SNR Estimator Probe block?

I will be glad to see the answers to at least a few questions.